# How to split Cupertino/Material in Flutter app depending on app platfrom?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create (and is it a good practice) a Flutter app which shows Cupertino UI widgets at iOS and Material UI widgets at Android with same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Flutter Platform Widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets) package, works fine

Answer (score 7):

Import `import 'dart:io'`
And then in your widget make if statement

```
if(Platform.isIOS){
...
} else {
...
}
```